# Testing a Windows service, for an application with client-server architecture

Tags: testing, windows-services, client-server

I am a software test engineer and want to test a new windows service for my application which has a client server architecture. The service keeps running on the background and checks for the database updates. It is developed by Delphi. The developers have debugged and tested the service. My question is what should be the testing approach to test a windows service, or what kind of test should a tester have to perform on a windows service? And how can this test be executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided, it's unclear whether you have access to the source code or not. Typically, testing against software is done with a testing framework against the source code using unit tests and integration tests.

If you do have access to the source code, the best course is to refactor any domain specific functionality out of the service project into a class library. You can then create a testing project which references the class library and write unit and integration tests against your classes.

If you do not have access to the source code, then you need to evaluate the software based on the task it is supposed to perform. You may have some specifications about what the software is expected to do. Compare the software's performance to any specifications that the software is supposed to meet.

The typical interface for a Windows service is Start and Stop. After you install the service and send those commands to the service, does it respond as expected?

Review the logs. Are there any exceptions being logged? Why are those exceptions occurring? Is there information that you need in the logs to evaluate performance that isn't there?